# Flutter release app native crash, abort error [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/library_loader.cc(24)] Check failed: result

Tags: android, flutter

Below is the log of the crash:

> Build fingerprint: 'google/walleye/walleye:9/PPR2.181005.003/4984323:user/release-keys'
>       Revision: 'MP1'
>       ABI: 'arm'
>       pid: 17914, tid: 17914, name: yapp.mobile.app  >>> myapp.mobile.app <<<
>       signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
>       Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/library_loader.cc(24)] Check failed: result. 
>       '

I do realize the *yapp.mobile.app* doesn't match my *applicationId* (*myapp.mobile.app*) and was wondering if that would cause a problem.

Also from what it looks like it could be my sqlite library which is from a flutter plugin using sflite for flutter, and not sure if the proguards I have set below will encompass that.

And I've read removing `minifyEnabled true`  in my *build.gradle* could be a possible fix.

Also I don't know  what that about message is trying to tell me, any help or guidance would be great.

*build.gradle*:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

*proguard-rules.pro*:

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
```

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: it said deleting build and nothing else so i'm not sure if it was already deleted or not, my guess it was because i never ran `flutter clean` before

Comment: Ok i was able to get the same error by adding a debug build type in my `build.gradle` so it doesn't seem that `flutter clean` worked for that error, but when i removed `minifyEnabled` it does work, but i would like to keep that in order to keep my code optimized

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was because of an lib that wasn't flagged to keep on `proguard-rules.pro`, then I changed like this:

```java
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-keep class vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.**  { *; }
-keep class com.baseflow.permissionhandler.**  { *; }
```

As I said, in my case, you can check if it's your case, by looking at the imports, at:

`/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant`.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, in my case I have placed *proguard-rules.pro* file in root directory instead of app folder, may help someone.